# Does "A is smaller than each of B and C" sound natural?

Tags: pronouns

A, B, and C have different sizes. Specifically, A is smaller than B and is also smaller than C.  In this case, which sentence sounds most natural and accurate?:

> 1. A is smaller than each of B and C.
> 2. A is smaller than either B or C.
> 3. A is smaller than B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite any of them, speaking as someone with graduate level mathematics education.

All three of those are grammatically and semantically valid, though the third is ambiguous because some people will take 'and' to mean 'plus'. Depending on context, the second might be taken as disjunctive - A is smaller than B, or A is smaller than C. However, I would say "**A is smaller than both B and C**" is natural and not ambiguous.